# Find continuous curvature approximation for going from a straight line into a half circle

Tags: interpolation, spline, bezier-curve

I have the problem that I want to steer a 4 wheel robot. It should move on a straight line, and for turning to go on a circle with a defined radius, as in this picture:
[image: path]

The problem I have is that if I move on a straight line and then enter the circle, the curvature suddenly changes which would lead to a sudden steering angle change for the robot. I tried using a cubic spline interpolation, which makes the curvature continuous, but there is still a lot of change in curvature during a small amount of time (in practice still leading to a sudden steering angle change). Is there a way to approximate this to go smoothly into such a curve?

Edit: Is there an interpolation that would have continuously increasing curvature?

Comment: Try using quintic Hermite curve. It allows you to interpolate curvature at two ends. However, it does not guarantee monotonic curvature though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this wiki article about Harmonic Drives might be helpful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_drive

There are also many publications on the topic of *Circular Splines* that you should search for.

Comment: I fear I don't understand how the Harmonic drive relates to this problem. I searched for circular splines and read a bit. My problem is not the approximation of the circle with splines but rather going from a straight line into the circle. If possible, the steering angle would only change slowly, preferably only into increasing curvature.